# unity: fix Player passing through objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After updating from unity 5.5.2 to 2017.3 the Player character does not collide with objects(evironment asset) and is passing through them, all the objects have mesh collider with convex on, This is only happening in one of the level(scene) in the game while in rest of the level(scene) the player behaves normal and is colliding with objects.

**Player settings**

[image]

**object settings**

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the issue is.  Not clear for you comments.  Can you also reference in the posted code what the problem is?

Comment: edited @jdweng !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player's rigidbody is kinematic. I would try by disabling that property.

Comment: Why does it cause problem ?

Comment: Well, if you want read more, there is an explanation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html. But, basically speaking, kinematic objects register collisions, but they aren't controlled by the physics system - just through script ("While the Rigidbody is marked isKinematic, it will not be affected by collisions, forces, or any other part of the physics system. This means that you will have to control the object by manipulating the Transform component directly").